# Force Lion to boot 32 bit mode

Tags: macos, vpn

How can I force OSX Lion to boot into 32bit mode without having to hold 3 + 2 down on boot?

I have to use the Cisco VPN Client to connect back into work and since upgrading it no longer works on 64bit. Cisco have dropped support for the client as well.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Cisco VPN client built-in into Mac OS X. I am currently using it successfully to connect to my university VPN network from home.

Add it as an interface in Network Preferences -

[image]

Quickly connect to the VPN from the menubar -

[image]

Comment: The OSX client requires a shared secret which the VPN connection doesn't have.

Comment: @digital It does. Under advanced options. I use it everyday

Comment: The VPN setup itself doesn't have one to my knowledge and the OSX VPN connection requires it. Should have worded it better.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the com.apple.Boot.plist (found in /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration) file with start parameters and also the desired architecture (if you add that section to the file). See the man page [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/com.apple.Boot.plist.5.html).

Comment: Does using *sudo systemsetup -setkernelbootarchitecture i386* to set this, instead of editing the plist file, work in Lion?